# CKEditor placeholder text doesn't work (config.js)

Tags: 7, javascript, wysiwyg

I'm trying to add placeholder text to my ckeditor screen like for example `Type here ...` . You can do this with the [configuration helper plugin](http://ckeditor.com/addon/confighelper).

I've placed the ckeditor library in `sites/all/libries`. I've pasted the plugin in `sites/all/libraries/ckeditor/plugins`. Then I've added the following code to my **config.js** (in ckeditor folder).

```
CKEDITOR.editorConfig = function( config ) {
    // Define changes to default configuration here. For example:
    // config.language = 'fr';
    // config.uiColor = '#AADC6E';
    config.extraPlugins='confighelper'; 
    config.placeholder = 'Type here...';
};
```

But this doesn't work. The **config.js** isn't added to my page when there's a ckeditor. The code is also not in **ckeditor.js** (which is loaded on the page, I thought that the plugin maybe added it to the file).

I've also tried to add the code to my **script.js** which is **always** loaded like this:

```
(function ($, Drupal, window, document, undefined) {
    Drupal.behaviors.my_custom_behavior = {
      attach: function(context, settings) {
        CKEDITOR.editorConfig = function( config ) {
          // Define changes to default configuration here. For example:
          // config.language = 'fr';
          // config.uiColor = '#AADC6E';
          config.extraPlugins='confighelper';
          config.placeholder = 'Type here...';
        };
      }
    };
})(jQuery, Drupal, this, this.document);
```

But still no result... . I'm using `CKEditor 4.4.2.1567b48` . Text format is filtered html. The ckeditor works but I can't add any plugins (I would also like youtube plugin). Also cleared my cache a couple of times.

Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 1):

A solution that avoids patching the wysiwyg module is the following:

You can use the hook `hook_wysiwyg_plugin($editor, $version)` that wysiwyg offers, in order to add the ckeditor plugin, as follows:

```
function custom_wysiwyg_plugin($editor, $version) {
  $plugins = array();
  switch ($editor) {
    case 'ckeditor':
      $plugins['confighelper'] = array(
        'extensions' => array('confighelper' => t('Configuration Helper')),
        'url' => 'http://ckeditor.com/addon/confighelper',
        'load' => TRUE,
        'internal' => TRUE,
      );
      break;
  }
  return $plugins;
}
```

Then, go to the wysiwig profile edit page and enable the Configuration Helper plugin.

After that, placeholder text will be shown in the wysiwyg ckeditor.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you are using wysiwyg with ckeditor.

The problem is that wysiwyg pass the configuration to the editor, in our case ckeditor, based on the options selected on the wysiwyg profile in use.

The solution i found sure it's not the best buts works for me. It's about modifying the wysiwyg file thats sets the configuration for ckeditor.

Open `site/all/modules/wysiwyg/editors/ckeditor.inc` and find the function `wysiwyg_ckeditor_settings`, then, before the code implode the $extra_plugins array add your extra plugins.

before:

```
if (!empty($extra_plugins)) {
  $settings['extraPlugins'] = implode(',', $extra_plugins);
}
```

add:

```
$extra_plugins[] = 'confighelper';
```

result:

```
$extra_plugins[] = 'confighelper';
if (!empty($extra_plugins)) {
  $settings['extraPlugins'] = implode(',', $extra_plugins);
}
```

Hope it helps.